# why does 5.00 > 20.00 returns true for javascript parseFloat.tofixed(2)

Tags: javascript

I am confused wit this since if I remove te .toFixed(2) then the condition will return false and thus be correct, but if there is .toFixed(2) it returns true which is wrong.

Also when I used console.log to display the two variables containing the values they both return this value

```
5.00 and 20.00
```

this is the code:

```
//this two values are actually populated from .val of an input field
var coupon_limit2 = 0;
var coupon_limit = $("#product_coupon_limit").val();
var sale_price = $("#product_product_list_price").val();


if(disc_type == "Percentage"){
            if(coupon_type == "amount"){
                coupon_limit2 = (coupon_limit/sale_price)*100;
            }else{
                coupon_limit2 = coupon_limit;
            }
        }else{
            if(coupon_type == "percent"){
                coupon_limit2 = (coupon_limit/100)*sale_price;
            }else{
                coupon_limit2 = coupon_limit;
            }
        }

var x = parseFloat($("#product_product_discount").val()).toFixed(2);
var y = coupon_limit2;

//returns correctly
if(x > parseFloat(y)){
   alert("hi"); 
}

//returns wrong
if(x > parseFloat(y).toFixed(2)){
   alert("hi"); 
}
```

I am already using the without .toFixed(2) since that's what's working properly but I just hope to have an explanation as to why this is happening.

Thank you

Comment: Because you're comparing strings.

Comment: @vlaz even if I parsed it to float?

Comment: why not compare raw values?

Comment: ^^ That.  `.toFixed()` returns a string.  Compare the values before you do any required formatting.

Comment: @hungrykoala because you are NOT representing it as a float - `toFixed` returns a string.

Comment: @hungrykoala: After parsing to float, you're doing `toFixed`. `toFixed` returns a string.

Comment: oh from what i googled for restricting the decimal places, it was said to use toFixed. Never did I know that it will then return string after that.

Comment: @hungrykoala the _only_ way to format numbers is to represent them as text. After all `5` and `5.0` and `5.00` are the _exact_ same number, in JS, hence only `5` is displayed, the rest of the numbers will be truncated to that when the numeric type is displayed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `toFixed` returns a **string**, and in a string comparison, anything starting with `"5"` is greater than anything starting with `"2"`.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var x = 5.0;
var y = 20.0;
console.log(typeof x);    // number
console.log(x > y);       // false
var xstr = x.toFixed(2);
var ystr = y.toFixed(2);
console.log(typeof xstr); // string
console.log(xstr > ystr); // true
```

Comment: I just assumed toFixed is for decimal places, I just googled how to restrict decimal places in js. Thank you for clarifying this matter to me. I'm sorry for being such a noob here

Comment: @hungrykoala: Unless there's a duplicate saying it as clearly as your question does, noob is absolutely fine. :-) Other people can now find this information in a similar search.

Comment: I assumed there would be a duplicate, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things with me, and typeof will be really useful in the future.